# How to write lines to Activity widow like Console.WriteLine()

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to write real time log data in an Activity window from a Service to watch what is happening. Like `Console.WriteLine.Log.I()`, but that isn't good for real time. If I write to a TextView, I need to periodically refresh the Activity and save data in `onDestroy()` when the screen orientation is changed. It is complex, and I don't now how to refresh the Activity from a static method.  What is a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good idea will be writing logs to a certain log file on SD card and then when your `Activity` is in foreground you just need to load the file contents to your `TextView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: So i need timer to periodically load to  contents to your TextView. Timer will call static Callback method. How i will refresh activity from static method?

Comment: @user1451579, Just call textView.setText() with new log contents and the TextView will refresh automatically.

Comment: Thanks! It work treak was that i had tou use not just delagate: private void UpdateText(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)  { tv.Text = Log.text;}   . But 
          private void UpdateText(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(delegate
            {
                tv.Text = Log.text;
            });
        }

Comment: @user1451579, That's right, you can't touch your views from a thread other than UI thread. Please accept the answer if you've found it useful.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation
(click on this box to dismiss) :)